# int to unsigned char* and vice versa

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am new to C/C++. After a long research, I need your help for this. I just want to store a number in `unsigned char*` and then bring the number back.

```
int nu = 50;
unsigned char byteArray[sizeof(int)];
memcpy(byteArray, &nu, sizeof(int));

int newNu = reinterpret_cast<int>(byteArray);
```

Im expecting the newNu will be 50, instead, it's not. Could anybody show me where am I wrong?

For the `int`->`unsign char*` I think I was correct, but how to reverse the progress? is it the right way? btw, I compiled this on `Visual Studio`

Comment: If you are new to C++ don't touch arrays, pointers, memcpy, and especially reinterpret_cast with a six foot pole.

Comment: thank you all, I just have begun to self-learn C/C++ for a few months. Agree that messing with memory management is such a pain. I will step slow now...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your cast converts the address of the array into a number.

The correct way to get the value out is:

```
int newNu;
memcpy(&newNu, byteArray, sizeof newNu);
```

Note: a naive attempt would be:

```
newNu = *reinterpret_cast<int *>(byteArray);
```

however this violates the [strict aliasing rule](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/959), as well as potentially being an alignment violation.  Do not do this. Warning: You may see this mistake repeated in various (not very good) references.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do it!!!

But in case you are just experiencing...

This part is incorrect:

```
int newNu = reinterpret_cast<int>(byteArray);
```

You are casting the address of the `char` array to `int` which is definitely not 50...

This is the code to get what you expect:

```
int newNu = *reinterpret_cast<int*>(byteArray);
```

Also pay attention to the parameters order in `memcpy`...
It should be

```
memcpy(&newNu, byteArray, sizeof newNu);
```